# Write a bash script to rm a directory and replace with a symlinked directory

Tags: bash

I just found out that one of the plugins that is on my server has a security flaw and I'd like to delete all of those versions of the plugins.  But I recently started learning how to run a single master copy of each plugin and WordPress itself by installing WordPress in a multi-tenant fashion.

Through some Googling I was able to find the correct command to search my server for all occurrences of the plugin name.  So I've run find / -type d -name 'plugin_name' and now have a list of directories that look like /home/rentals/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name

I'm trying to create a bash script that will go through each line of the text file and then delete the directory that currently exists and then create a new directory that is symlinked to a different location.

My file looks like this:

```
/home/rentals/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack    
/home/beachcon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack    
/home/sellingo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack
```

My pseudo code looks something like this.

- Initialize our variables including the symlink directory.
  `$symlink_directory = /opt/wordpress/plugins/all-in-one-seo`
  `$sym_plugin_directory = /all-in-one-seo`
- Grab line from list of directories in `myfile.csv`
- Throw that into a variable lets call it `$var1`
- `rm` the directory stored in `$var1`  ( `rm -rf $var1` )
- Create a symlink to our directory using... ( `ln -s $var1 $symlink_directory` )

The truth though is that I only know some basic php and what I've been able to Frankenstein together here isn't far enough along.  Can someone assist?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat myfile.csv | while read line
do
    rm -rf "$var1" && ln -s "$var1" "$symlink_directory"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this script does what you want. I was a little confused about which directory contained the folders to be deleted but hopefully the script is self-explanatory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory containing plugins to be removed
plugin_dir="/opt/wordpress/plugins/"

while read line
do
    # slice final part of directory name from line in file
    # (remove everything up to the final /)
    plugin_name=${line##*/}
    # full path to directory which will be removed
    dir="$plugin_dir/$plugin_name"
    # remove directory and create symbolic link to path from file
    rm -rf "$dir" && ln -s "$line" "$dir"
done < myfile
```

---

#### update

Based on your edits to the code, I think that this is a lot simpler than I first thought:

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory containing plugins to be removed
plugin_dir="/opt/wordpress/plugins/all-in-one-seo"

while read dir
do
    # remove directory and create symbolic link to path from file
    rm -rf "$dir" && ln -s "$plugin_dir" "$dir"
done < myfile
```

Comment: Tom thank you for taking the time to help me.  Here is an example of the existing directories that exist in the text file.  Each line of the text file has a different "record"

/home/beachcon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack
/home/sellingo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack
/home/mpgaller/public_html/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack

These are the directories that need to be deleted, and also the name of the directory that needs to be recreated with the symlink.

Hopefully that clears things up slightly.

Comment: As I am re-reading this I am thinking that perhaps I don't need to do any cut or trimming.  I might have been over thinking this.

Comment: @Scott if you have additional details, you should edit your answer to add them in.

Comment: I made edits above.  Incorporating some of your code to get me that much closer.  See if that reads more direct on what I am trying to accomplish.